# Spring boot Invalid UTF-8 middle byte on specific machine when sending request with Hebrew

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, character-encoding

I am using Spring boot mvc and I have an issue that is reproduced only on my staging machine, but works fine locally.

I am sending the following JSON reqeust (notice Hebrew chars under "whatever" field):

```
{
 "messageInitiaterId":"0542258808",
 "destinationId":"0544556543",
 "whatever":"משהו",
 "pushToken":"e2eeb632-8c2c-4ad2-a163-cfeb671d1955",
 "androidVersion":"7.1.1",
 "deviceModel":"huawei nexus 6p",
 "appVersion":"1.42"
}
```

Locally, it returns a response and all is well. On the staging machine, this is the response returned:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1485591099485,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception":          

    "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x3f\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6996e7d; line: 4, column: 17]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x3f\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6996e7d; line: 4, column: 17]",
  "path": "/v1/IsRegistered"

}
```

Currently using Postman to reproduce this. The header on the request is:

```
"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

I also tried to add the Hebrew language to the machine itself, which is running Windows 8, but it did not seem to make a difference.

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT*:**

This is the controller, adding the suggested `MediaType` but still getting the same error:

```
@Controller
public class IsRegisteredController extends AbstractController {

private final IsRegisteredLogic logic;

@Autowired
public IsRegisteredController(IsRegisteredLogic logic) {
    this.logic = logic;
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/IsRegistered", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Response<UserDTO> isRegistered(@Valid @RequestBody IsRegisteredRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return logic.execute(request, response);
}
}
```

***EDIT2:***

Tried the suggestions below, as well as others I found online, all of which did not make a difference. This seems to be a more difficult problem than I thought.

Added to application.properties the following fields:

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.datasource.connectionproperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

As well as the following beans:

```
@Bean
public TomcatConnectorCustomizer tomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
    return connector -> connector.setURIEncoding("UTF-8");
}

@Bean
public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    return characterEncodingFilter;
}
```

All is to no avail. What's going on here? Surely Spring boot can handle Hebrew chars in requests...

Comment: Are you sending the request from the same client (locally and in stage)?

Comment: Yes, same local Postman client reproduces the issue on staging, but works fine when running the server locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between your local development machine and the staging machine is quite obviously that they are configured with different language and text encoding settings. To work around it, explicitly specify the text encoding when starting the JVM for your application:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You can even set the following properties in `application.properties` to prevent Tomcat from starting if the encoding isn't configured properly:

```
spring.mandatory_file_encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller method @RequestMapping, explicitly set consumes to application/json;charset=UTF-8

Sample:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "your_url", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but unfortunately I am getting the same error. I will edit my question to add the controller.

Comment: The `consumes` annotation works as a filter. It says: if a request comes in, do not call this method unless the content type is "application/json". It has not effect for the output or the interpretation of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the file `application.properties`:

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8 # Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true # Enable http encoding support.
spring.http.encoding.force=true # Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
```

The last line might not be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still getting the same error though. I found this entry when I restarted my server, not sure if it is related or not: `o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tomcat? If yes, you have to make sure that your tomcat's server.xml's file connector element has URIEncoding attribute which value is UTF-8.

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
 maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
 enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
 connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
 compression="on" 
 compressionMinSize="128" 
 noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Spring boot which is using Tomcat behind the scenes, so I did not need to configure server.xml, web.xml or anything else beyond application.properties. The rest is in-code configuration. Is there any way to set URIEncoding in Spring boot's inner tomcat instance? _EDIT:_ I found this: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/540) I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it. Still the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you solved this until today? I have the same issue in version 2.0.0.