# JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle, method POST Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, utf-8

I'm developing an application, it is basically an rest api but I'm having problems with POST method because when I want to send a request (it's a json), in a of the fields I can put a text with words accented (is a spanish text), but when my application recives the request, I get this error: "Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle".

Controller Code

```
@PostMapping(path= "/traduccion", consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<String> obtenerTraduccion(
        @RequestBody TranslateString translateString) {
    
    String respuestaTraduccion = null;
    
    try {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Petición para obtener la traducción");
        respuestaTraduccion = clienteDDBO.translateString(translateString);
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Obtenida la respuesta de Plata");
    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage1());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return ResponseEntity.created(URI
            .create("/respuesta/"))
            .body(respuestaTraduccion);
}
```

TranslateString Code

```
public class TranslateString {

    private Boolean proxyCache;
    private String translationEngine; 
    private String documentBase64;
    private String languagePair;
    private Boolean ner;
    private String contentType; 
    private String markUnknown; 
    private String codeTranslate; 
    private String checksum; 
    private String url; 
    private String dirbase;
    
    
    
    public TranslateString(Boolean proxyCache, String translationEngine, String documentBase64, String languagePair,
            Boolean ner, String contentType, String markUnknown, String codeTranslate, String checksum, String url,
            String dirbase) {
        super();
        this.proxyCache = proxyCache;
        this.translationEngine = translationEngine;
        this.documentBase64 = documentBase64;
        this.languagePair = languagePair;
        this.ner = ner;
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.markUnknown = markUnknown;
        this.codeTranslate = codeTranslate;
        this.checksum = checksum;
        this.url = url;
        this.dirbase = dirbase;
    }
    More getter/setter
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907868/spring-boot-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte-on-specific-machine-when-sending-request-w already?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes, I saw, I have already done and anything, I have same mistake.